# findOneAndUpdate seems to be doubling my $inc count

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to post a comment on to my posts for my MERN app but I'm running into an issue where the comment (Posts.findOneAndUpdate) seems to posting the comments twice. I read a few posts on SO that described the issue to be the way mongoose handles queries but I must be missing something.

If anyone could explain what I'm doing wrong I would greatly appreciate it!

Route I'm using:

```
router.post('/newReply/:id', async function(req, res) {
    const body = req.body

    if (!body) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            success: false,
            error: 'No text entered!',
        })
    }

    const reply = new Replies(body)
    if (!reply) {
        return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: err })
    }

    await Posts.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: req.params.id },
        {
            "$inc": { "replies": 1 },
            "$push": { "comments": reply },
        },
        {
            new: true
        },
        (err) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(404).json({
                    success: false,
                    error: err,
                    message: 'Post not found!',
                })
            }
            return res.status(200).json({ 
                success: true,
                id: reply._id,
                message: 'Reply created!',
                reply: reply.reply,
                points: reply.points,
                createdAt: reply.createdAt
            })
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    })
```

Posts Model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const PostsSchema = new Schema({
  post: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  points: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },
  voters: {
    type: Array
  },
  upvotedBy: {
    type: Array
  },
  downvotedBy: {
    type: Array
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  replies: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },
  comments: {
    type: Array
  },
  user_id: {
    type: 'string'
  },
  deleted: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  }
});

module.exports = Posts = mongoose.model("posts", PostsSchema);
```

Comment: Is `Replies` is a mongoose schema ? You actually don't need this :: `    const reply = new Replies(body)
    if (!reply) {
        return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: err })
    }` Also here `{ _id: req.params.id }` you need to convert 'req.params.id' from `string` to `ObjectId()` , Here :: `"$push": { "comments": reply }` you can directly push 'body', `"$push": { "comments": body }`, Try these & let us know if there are any issues.

Comment: @whoami Hi! Thanks for the help, correct that `Replies` is a mongoose Schema. I've made the appropriate changes you outlined above but I'm still running into the duplicate issues unfortunately. Let me know if there's any other code you'd like to see!

Comment: Enable some sort of logging so you can see when the `/newReply/:id` router is engaged.  If the browser, proxy, profiler, prefetcher, or antimalware software cause the request to be sent twice, it will be updated twice.  If the request is getting duplicated, you might protect against this by having a unique value included in each page sent out and returned with each request so you can identify duplicates.